# Why does printing once every 100k iterations ruin the numba performance?

Tags: python, printing, jit, numba

Why does this code, with a `print` once every 100k iterations (i.e. *only 40 lines* are printed!) take 50 seconds to run:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def doit():
    A = np.random.random(4*1000*1000)
    n = 300
    Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
        if i % 100000 == 0:  # print the progress once every 100k iterations
            print("%i %.2f %% already done. " % (i, i * 100.0 / len(A)))

doit()
```

whereas, without the `print`, **it only takes 2.4 seconds**:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit
def doit():
    A = np.random.random(4*1000*1000)
    n = 300
    Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
doit()
```

**?**

Is this a general fact that `print` can really remove the benefit of `numba`?

Comment: You also removed the `i % 100000` calculation.

Comment: In your first example you're asking the loop to do an extra thing in *each iteration* to perform a check, and when you loop over 4 million times even if the operation only takes 0.01 millisecond to run, it adds up to ~40 seconds total runtime.

Comment: Actually I think `i % 100000` is not the problem, if you change `print` to `pass`, it will be much quicker. And further `print` itself is also not the key point. Instead, converting a number into string is the point as sometimes it is really slow.

Comment: @khelwood Does it really take 10 µs to compute `i % 100000` or do a `if`? I really doubt this is true. Computing a modulo seems to be negligible in comparison to `np.sum(A[i:i+300] <= A[i+300])`...

Comment: @Sraw Converting the number to string only happens 40 times. I think it can't explain the 40 more seconds.

Comment: You can test it by yourself. Change `print` to `pass` and see. Or `print("some fixed string instead")`.

Comment: @Sraw strange ineed... how can a single float to string conversion take 1 second ?

Comment: @Basj I wasn't saying it did. I just meant that _printing 40 lines_ is not the only think the first version does that the second does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to compile it with `@njit` or `@jit(nopython=True)`, you'll see that it's compiling in object mode from the exception. This version runs in about 1 sec on my machine with the print statement:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def doit():
    A = np.random.random(4*1000*1000)
    n = 300
    Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
        if i % 100000 == 0:  # print the progress once every 100k iterations
            print(i , "(",  i * 100.0 / len(A), '% already done)')
```

In general if you are seeing poor performance from a numba function, it is because you are compiling in python object mode, so always putting `nopython=True` is a good practice unless you really want to use it in python object mode because it will fall back to that if it runs into some bit of syntax that the compiler can't compile down to machine code. Numba does do some loop lifting, but that's harder to reason about in terms of performance.

See:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this example, what made numba switch to slow `object mode` instead of keeping normal "fast mode"?

Comment: It was the unsupported string formatting in the `print` function.

Comment: Which string formatting @JoshAdel would be supported?